# ASP.NET Core Web API returns unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: ssl, dns, certificate, asp.net-core-webapi

Attempting to call an ASP.NET Core Web API from localhost and mobile devices but I get an error

> Unable to get local issuer certificate

The API runs fine from web browser and Postman. Since the error indicates that maybe a certificate on the web host with the API cannot be accessed, point another domain that issues SSL certificates to a static IP address on the host w/ the API. That is, create a DNS record ("A") on the 2nd domain with the static IP but to no avail.

Help is appreciated